# Create posts from json source in Jekyll

Tags: arrays, json, loops, jekyll

I have a json source like,

```
{
    "values": [
        ["post - content", "post - image link", "post - title name"],
        ["post - content", "post - image link", "post - title name"],
        ["post - content", "post - image link", "post - title name"],
        ["post - content", "post - image link", "post - title name"],
        ["post - content", "post - image link", "post - title name"],
        ["post - content", "post - image link", "post - title name"]
......
    ]
}
```

My source is https://script.google.com/macros/s/AKfycbyHFt1Yz96q91-D6eP4uWtRCcF_lzG2WM-sjrpZIr3s02HrICBQ/exec
Can I make normal Jekyll posts from this, if yes please explain. Thanks.

Comment: I think you have to write a generator: https://jekyllrb.com/docs/plugins/your-first-plugin/

Comment: Can we use javascript loop and create posts with this